# IntelliJ "FileNotFoundException", File Exists

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

My objective is to read a text file on IntelliJ. 
However, when I ran my codes, I get a "FileNotFoundException" message. My file exists. I triple-checked to make sure that the path is correct. I've scoured Stack Overflow looking for an answer, read every question I've come across, but no one offered a concrete solution to the issue.

This is my code:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;


    public class LetterGrader {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

           String curDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
           System.out.println("Current sys dir: " + curDir);


           try {
               File inputData = new File("input.txt");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputData));

           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("File not found");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
```

This is the error message that showed up.

```
    File not found
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at LetterGrader.main(LetterGrader.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! When I find a solution, I will respond back, too.

[UPDATE]

I solved the issue by moving my "input.txt" file out or src folder and into the main project's folder.

I also used Scanner instead of BufferedReader.

My final code that worked:

```
        try {
            Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
            while (diskScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(diskScanner.nextLine());
            }
            diskScanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: most likely `inputData` doesn't point to the file you think it points to. Try with absolute path or simply try to print the absolute path of `inputData` and look what the output is.

Comment: Print `System.getProperty("user.dir");` and see if the directory is the one where the file is. If not, use `getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: I got the absolute path and the file is there for sure, but still error message. :(

Comment: Are you sure the file extension is not messed up? Few times in Windows file extensions are hidden for a known types. Try listing all files from respective directory using your program and see if it lists input.txt

Comment: @Jack I checked the directory, and it lists as "File input" after I ran the program.

Comment: Add the output of the program to the question. Also add the output of the program when you listed the files in the directory

Comment: "I solved the issue by moving my "input.txt" file out of src folder and into the main project's folder."  Yes that worked for me too :-)

Answer (score 7):

The issue is because of the differences in the working directory, i.e., the directory where your source code resides and the current working directory of `IntelliJ` is different. Generally, the working directory is the main directory of your project.
So, either you place your file in that directory, or use `Edit Configurations...` option. After selecting `Edit Configurations...`, check out the option `Working directory` and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to print absolute path of the file first

```
System.out.println(new File("input.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

Then, since you are using IntelliJ, you can open terminal right in IDE and try to open this file from there. For example:

```
cat /Users/antonpp/Documents/Projects/testapp/input.txt
```

So, you will be totally sure that file exists and it is in the right place.

Comment: I got the absolute path, and the same error message popped up.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I also have some problems about that. So try `Edit Configurations`. You can find it at Run -> Edit Configurations.. Then edit `Working directory` to where your file locates. By the way, you can edit it to base directory and add path in your code.